# ¿Puede cambiarse el comportamiento de un alert de asincrono a sincrono?

Tags: javascript

se que a lo mejor puede parecer una pregunta muy sencilla, pero resulta que siempre me pasa eso, y es que si quiero mostrar en pantalla algun resultado con un alert(), en javascript, resulta que el código por alguna razón primero lee y ejecuta el alert(), y despues ejecuta el código!

Lo que quiero es que primero se ejecute lo que debe de ejecutarse, y luego se ejecute el alert(), un ejemplo sencillo seria:

```
console.log("Hola mundo");//Quiero que primero se ejecute por ejemplo esto antes del alert()!

alert(`Puntuación: ${puntuacion} ptos`);
//Fin del programa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es una "ilusión". El `alert` es síncrono pero hace que el agente/navegador pause la ejecución. La operación se ha realizado, pero su efecto no se ve en la interfaz porque hay un tiempo de refresco. Pero realmente la operación se  ha realizado.

Por ejemplo, con el mismo código que tienes (he añadido la variable que faltaba), abre las herramientas del desarrollador (dependiendo del navegador y sistema operativo, con <kbd>F12</kbd> o <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) y ve a la consola. Después ejecuta el snippet siguiente:

```js
console.log("Hola mundo");
const puntuacion = 3;
alert(`Puntuación: ${puntuacion} ptos`);
```

Como verás, el mensaje de "Hola Mundo" se ve en la consola del navegador antes del `alert` pero no en la ventana de resultado. Cuando cierras el `alert` sí se ve en la ventana. Eso puede dar la impresión de que el `alert` es "asíncrono", pero  no es el caso. Realmente se debe a que el refresco de la ventana no es instantáneo, tarda unos pocos milisegundos (alrededor de 16 si no recuerdo mal) y en ese tiempo se ejecuta el `alert`. Pero repito: las operaciones se han realizado ya, aunque la interfaz no se haya actualizado.

Si el problema es que quieres que la interfaz se actualice antes del `alert`, una cosa que puedes hacer es añadirle un pequeño retardo usando `setTiemout`. Ni siquiera le tienes que poner un tiempo. Eso hará que el `alert` se ponga en la cola de acciones a ejecutar y, cuando se llegue a él (de manera casi inmediata, una manera no notará retraso alguno).

Como puedes ver  en el siguiente ejemplo, ahora se ve el mensaje en la pantalla antes de que se abra el `alert`:

```js
console.log("Hola mundo");
const puntuacion = 3;
setTimeout(() => alert(`Puntuación: ${puntuacion} ptos`))
```

Comment: Como nota aparte, hacer uso de pausas (como la que causa el `alert`) es algo que no se recomienda porque puede dar una mala experiencia de usuario. Puedes leer sobre eso en la [definición del estándar HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#pause) (en inglés).

Comment: Se me habia olvidado que podia hacer un setTimeOut,  y realmente el código de arriba era un ejemplo, todo eso si lo ejecutas en una función a mi me ejecuta primero el alert, y hasta que no le de aceptar para que el alert se cierre, no se ejecuta ni lo que esta antes ni lo que esta despues de hecho... por lo que el tiempo de refresco que dices imagino que se ejecuta despues de que se cierre el alert?

Comment: Hice, una prueba mas... el console.log funcióna bien como tu dices con el alert()!, sin embargo pense que no funcionaria bien... es que el código que tengo no lo estaba probando con un console.log, lo que estaba intentando era algo como esto:                                                                                                             

audio.play()
alert(//aqui el alert dictara los puntos);

pero sorpresa sorpresa!, el audio se ejecuta despues del alert... comportamiento un tanto extraño... pero de todas maneras... muchas gracias!, me ayudo tu respuesta estoy agradecido.

Comment: Voy a usar setTimeOut para corregirlo.

Comment: @Riven Ten en cuenta que el `play` de un elemento no es automático sino una operación asíncrona que devuelve una promesa (porque el audio/video puede no haberse cargado o puede haber operaciones previas). Eso causará que el `alert` se ejecute "antes", pause el navegador, y si hay alguna otra operación esperando a ser ejecutada (el `play()`), se ejecute  después de cerrar el `alert`. Si quieres que el `audio` comience antes del `alert`, puedes usar el `setTimeout` o, para asegurarte de que todo se ejecuta en orden, haz que el `alert` se lance en el `then` de la promesa (y precarga el sonido).